# How to determine if the following function is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following function:

$$\frac{(3z^2 - \bar{z})^2 \bar{z}}{2}$$

I need to determine whether or not the function is holomorphic. Do I need to go through the Cauchy-Riemann equation or is there a simpler way to determine it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Hint: Use Identity Theorem for $f(z)-f(\overline z)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cauchy-Riemann equation can be written in a simpler form $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial{\bar z}}=0$$

In other words, a differentiable function is holomorphic iff it depends on only $z$, not $\bar z$.

Another way: on the unit circle, $\bar z = \frac{1}{z}$, so $f(z)=g(z)$ where $g(z)=\frac{(3z^2-\frac{1}{z})^2}{2z}$. If $f(z)$ is holomorphic, then $f(z)\equiv g(z)$ everywhere on $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$ by the uniqueness of holomorphic extension. But $$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}f(z)=0\not=\infty =\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}g(z)$$

A third way would be to use the suggestion of @geetha290krm in the comment. Since $f(z)\in\mathbb R$ whenever $z\in\mathbb R$, by the Schwarz reflection principle, $f(\bar z)=\overline{f(z)}$ if $f$ is holomorphic, but one can check this isn't the case.